# Generate PDF using svg raw data in php

Tags: php, pdf, fabricjs

Is it possible to generate pdf using svg raw data (getting from fabric js) on php side?

I have searched a bit and found this example:

https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_058/

but its except svg image not the svg raw data, so how one can generate pdf using svg raw data on server side using php?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass your `svg` raw data to `ImageSVG`

```
$svgRaw = '<svg height="80" width="300">
  <g fill="none">
    <path stroke="red" d="M5 20 l215 0" />
    <path stroke="black" d="M5 40 l215 0" />
    <path stroke="blue" d="M5 60 l215 0" />
  </g>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>';


$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $svgRaw, $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);

$pdf->Write(0, $txt='', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```